# Link not showing image on Facebook

Tags: image, facebook, hyperlink

I am trying to post my website to my Facebook account as a link. It is not showing the link rel image that I've specified. I've been toying with this for several hours today and not getting any results. I've added the link rel tag in the head and I've pointed the path to the space where the image is found. No luck. Can anyone help?

Here is the website: http://www.aboutaburningfire.com

Here is my Facebook link: http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1406827330#!/aburningfire

Answer (score 0):

Change http:www.aboutaburningfire.com/images/thumbnail.jpg to:

http://www.aboutaburningfire.com/images/thumbnail.jpg

You forgot the forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I see you currently are using http://aboutaburningfire.com/images/thumbnail.jpg
That URL doesn't seem to work, I've tried to put it in my browser, and the page is not found. If I add www it works, http://www.aboutaburningfire.com/images/thumbnail.jpg
Try changing that, if you haven't already.

**EDIT**

Check this out: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aboutaburningfire.com%2F

The image can not be found.